# apt-get update: Segmentation fault

Tags: ubuntu, apt-get

Ubuntu 14.04

When I run `apt-get update`

`Fetched 3432 kB in 32s (105 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Error!
Segmentation fault`

I tried 
`rm -rf /var/cache/apt/*.bin` and `apt-get clean` and `rm -rf /var/log/apt` and `rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*`

All does't work.

What should I do?